# YouTube API Using Zend_Gdata for 2 Latest Videos - Really Slow

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

I'm using Zend_Gdata, as described in the YouTube developer API docs, to try and simply pull in the latest two videos, with thumbnails. Unfortunately, it is incredibly slow and delays loading of the rest of the page, so I have had to disable this code and put in static HTML. I'm thinking that perhaps it is querying too much data, but I don't see a limit option for `getuserUploads`. The only other solution I can think of is having it do an AJAX call after the page loads, but I still need it to be faster.

If it would be faster to use the XML, can someone point me to some working code to grab the title, url, and thumbnail? The code I found and tried first (using a Simple XML function) did not work at all.

Here is the code used that is slow:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; 
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');

function printVideoFeed($videoFeed, $limit)
{
  $count = 1;
  foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) {
    if ($count > $limit) { break; }
    echo "<li>";
    printVideoEntry($videoEntry);
    echo "</li>\n";
    $count++;
  }
}
function getAndPrintUserUploads($userName)                    
{     
  //Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
  $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube(NULL, 'APPIDHERE', 'CLIENTNAMEHERE', 'ASDF-LONGDEVKEYHERE-TO-FIX-TOO-MANY-CALLS-PROBLEM');

  $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
  printVideoFeed( $yt->getuserUploads($userName), 2 );
}  
function printVideoEntry($videoEntry) 
{
    // get all thumbnails. Use the 2nd one (index of 1 in array) that is 180px wide
    $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails(); ?>

    <div class="theimg">
        <a href="<?php echo $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(); ?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?php echo $videoThumbnails[1]['url']; ?>" alt="" width="160" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <span class="date">Video</span>
    <h4><a href="<?php echo $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $videoEntry->getVideoTitle(); ?></a></h4>
} 

getAndPrintUserUploads('USERNAMEHERE');
```

Comment: If you don't have uploads every 2 seconds you could cache the data and fetch them only once a day.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance you're not using the full Zend MVC model, some things you could use to improve performance is to send methods that are handling HTML for the VIEW and use the RSS feeds from youtube to make this request.

Comment: The site is not in the Zend framework, if that is what you are referring to. It is using Zend_Gdata as described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php
If you know of any working code that uses the XML/RSS for the latest vids, let me know. I was assuming that would be a lot faster. The code I found through Google and StackOverflow wasn't working.